# Leitura de variável em C com timeout

Tags: c, variáveis, timeout, tempo-de-resposta

Alguém sabe como limitar o tempo que o usuário pode digitar um valor?

**Exemplo:**

Meu programa imprime um valor na tela e o usuário tem 4 segundos para digitar e dar enter, se o que que ele digitou for `=` ao valor impresso, o valor muda e conta um ponto, senão o valor muda e conta -1 ponto.

Comment: A solucao vai ser diferente para diferentes sistemas operativos. Diz se usas Windows, Linux, Android, nave espacial, controlador de elevador, ..., ... *(e le sobre [ncurses](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)) que eventualmente da para o teu SO*

Answer (score 1):

## Atualização

Reparei no que o [pmg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6594/pmg) disse e fui pesquisar melhor sobre o assunto, encontrei algumas coisas interessantes, tais como [este código](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5304/#msg23940) que funciona no linux, para além disso o autor referiu uma biblioteca chamada [NCurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), tendo também sido referida pelo [pmg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6594/pmg).

Também encontrei [uma questão no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226603/timeout-function) em que eles utilizaram a função `select`, entretanto eu pensei na utilização de threads então procurei novamente e [achei um código](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/61744-timeouts-input.html#post439507) que soluciona o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 
 
#define TIMEOUT 4000 //4 segundos em milisegundos
 
void getInput(LPVOID param);
 
 
int main() {
 
    DWORD myThreadID;
    HANDLE myThread;
    int userInput = 0;
 
    myThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)getInput, &userInput ,0, &myThreadID);
 
    WaitForMultipleObjects(1, &myThread, TRUE, TIMEOUT);
     
    CloseHandle(myThread);
 
    if(userInput != 0){
        printf("\nValor %d", userInput);
    }else
       printf("\nO tempo limite foi excedido.");
 
    return 0;
}
void getInput(LPVOID param){
    printf("Insira o valor: ");
    scanf("%d",(int)&param);
}
```

De qualquer forma irei manter as antigas soluções que eu tinha apresentado.

---

#### Utilizando Unix Timestamp

Podemos medir a diferença de tempos utilizando o Unix Timestamp, a ideia é muito simples, medimos o inicio e depois medimos o fim.

**Exemplo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
 
int main(void) {
    
    int valor; //variavel que guarda o "valor"
    printf("Insira um valor: "); 
    
    time_t _start = time(NULL); //medimos o tempo no instante inicial, ou seja, antes da execução do scanf.
    
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    
    time_t _end = time(NULL); //medimos o tempo no instante final, ou seja, depois da execuação do scanf.
        
    if((_end - _start) >= 4) //calculamos a diferença entre o final e o inicial, se o valor for superior a 4 então o tempo limite foi excedido.
    {
        printf("\nFoi excedido o tempo limite..");
    } else {
        printf("valor %d", valor);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Utilizando a função `clock`

O código é o mesmo o que muda é o uso da função clock e o retorno, em vez de retornar um valor em segundos este retorna em milisegundos, dai ser necessário a multiplicação por 1000.

```
int main(void) {
    
    int valor; //variavel que guarda o "valor"
    printf("Insira um valor: "); 
    
    clock_t _start = clock(); //medimos o tempo no instante inicial, ou seja, antes da execução do scanf.
    
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    
    clock_t _end = clock(); //medimos o tempo no instante final, ou seja, depois da execuação do scanf.
    
        
    if((_end - _start) >= (4*1000) //calculamos a diferença entre o final e o inicial, se o valor for superior a 4000 então o tempo limite foi excedido.
    {
        printf("\nFoi excedido o tempo limite..");
    } else {
        printf("valor %d", valor);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Utilizando o `QueryPerformanceCounter` e `QueryPerformanceFrequency`

Desde já agradeço ao [deepmax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952747/deepmax) por ter publicado um código de medida de tempo na questão: *[Measure execution time in C (on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720542/measure-execution-time-in-c-on-windows)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
     
int main(void) {
    
    LARGE_INTEGER _frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER _start;
    LARGE_INTEGER _end;
    double interval;
    
    int valor; //variavel que guarda o "valor"
    printf("Insira um valor: "); 
    
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&_frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&_start); //medimos o tempo no instante inicial, ou seja, antes da execução do scanf.
    
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&_end); //medimos o tempo no instante final, ou seja, depois da execuação do scanf.
    
    interval = (double) (_end.QuadPart - _start.QuadPart) / _frequency.QuadPart; //obtemos o intrevalo de tempo atravês da diferença entre o final e o inicial e a divisão da frequencia.

    
    if(interval >= 4.0) //verificamos se o intrevalo de tempo é superior a 4.0
    {
        printf("\nFoi excedido o tempo limite..");
    } else {
        printf("valor %d", valor);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Espero que estes exemplos-lhe dêem uma ideia básica de como medir o tempo e de como fazer uma limitação de tempo.

Comment: O problema, acho eu, nao é medir o tempo que o utilizador demora a dar input. O problema é fazer que ao fim de 3 segundos seja considerado input branco (ou coisa parecida) ... ou seja: nao podes usar `fgets()` (ou `scanf()` ou outro metodo "normal") directamente porque estas funcoes *bloqueiam*.

Comment: Bem na primeira lógica que eu tinha apresentado de facto o tempo é medido, mas é a partir dessa medição que eu calculo a diferença entre o inicio e o fim (*_end* - *_start*) e depois determinaria se já teriam passado 4 segundos. De qualquer forma pesquisei mais sobre o assunto e encontrei uma solução utilizando threads, para além disso encontrei também uma referência ao **NCurses**